# How can I write the Chinese colon "：" on Win10 keyboard?

Tags: technology

I couldn't any information on this question whatsoever and I tried every thinkable combination of keys...

Please can someone help? It gets a little annoying when I have to write Chinese texts that I always have to copy and paste this colon from the internet... :/

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which IME are you using? Isn't that going to be “：” under Chinese mode and ":" under English mode?

Comment: Why are you not saying what IME you're using, even after River asked you? The answer may very well depend on the IME you use.

Comment: It also depends on what keyboard layout you have. Are you using US keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a German QWERTZ keyboard you should press SHIFT + the key on the right of "L" (that is a "Ö").

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can only type in English punctuations under Chinese mode with the default IME in Win 10, try the keyboard shortcut `[Ctrl] + [.]` to switch it back.

Comment: You mean I should use the normal ":" colon instead of the Chinese one?

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions No, what River meant is, when you write Chinese text and want to write a Chinese colon "：", if you see that instead of "：" you get a ":", then try to press the CTRL key and, keeping CTRL pressed, the "." key. After that, try again to type the ":" key and you will see that you will get the Chinese colon "：".

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks! But I can't even write a ":" with the Chinese language setting.

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions Type SHIFT + the key on the right of "L".

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions BTW, do you have a QWERTY or QWERTZ keyboard?

Comment: OMG, you saved my day, thank you so much!!! I don't know why, but I couldn't find this Shift + Ö (my key next to L) key combination anywhere! How did you know that? By the way, I have a QWERTZ keyboard, but when I switch to Chinese (where I can shift from 英 to 中) it becomes a QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Prehaps try to install some Chinese keyboard overlay on your win10,

one such example would be 'Sogou keyboard', which is available on their official website @ https://pinyin.sogou.com/

Once set up correctly, you can just type colon normally and it will show up.